# Sort array of dates with date month and year in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to sort an array with a date but the date has only sort with date and month, and not sorting with year my code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrClassSehedule sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [appSharedData.CommanFormatForConditional dateFromString: [obj1 objectForKey:@"scheduleStart"]];
    NSDate *d2 = [appSharedData.CommanFormatForConditional dateFromString: [obj1 objectForKey:@"scheduleStart"]];
    return [d1 compare: d2];
}];
```

It's not sorting properly by date.

Comment: my issue is year is not including in sorting , sorting happending with dat and month only

Comment: What is the format of  `scheduleStart`?

Comment: You are getting Date string from same Dictionary Objects - `obj1`. Is this typo?

Comment: Please take a look at: [sorting an NSArray of NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355025/4061501)

Comment: Thanks @LalKrishna yes it was typo mistake  obj1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a typo.

Please replace the code with

```
 NSDate *d2 = [appSharedData.CommanFormatForConditional dateFromString: [obj2 objectForKey:@"scheduleStart"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for `d1` you are using `obj1` and for `d2` you also use `obj1`. So just a typo as Lal Krishna wrote. Here's the fixed version:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrClassSehedule sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [appSharedData.CommanFormatForConditional dateFromString:[obj1 objectForKey:@"scheduleStart"]];
    NSDate *d2 = [appSharedData.CommanFormatForConditional dateFromString:[obj2 objectForKey:@"scheduleStart"]];
    return [d1 compare:d2];
}];
```